# Is the wife's murder in Fargo a deleted scene?

Tags: fargo

In the movie [Fargo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116282/) two killers kidnap the wife of a car salesman in a deal that all goes wrong. While one of the killers is away at Twin Cities picking up the ransom, his partner stays at the cottage to watch the kidnapped wife.

When the guy returns with the ransom money to the cottage, he walks through the front door and sees the wife dead on the floor. He asks what happened and his partner says "She started screaming."

This is the only murder in the entire film that wasn't shown. All the other murders were graphic so I don't think it was censored. I'm left wondering if the scene of her death was a deleted scene, or is there a reason it wasn't shown.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The depiction of the other murders has a direct storytelling part in the plot or in the personality of each character.  The character of the two stupid guys (Carl and Grimsrud) are well established by that point—as is Jean (Jerry's wife)—so depicting the exact situation and murder is pointless.  It would be gratuitous and redundant.  By leaving it unseen, the audience is more engaged to contemplate:  *Would she have screamed?  What would the numbskulls have done?  Is this a likely, but stupid thing they would do?*

By not showing Jean's murder, the audience gets an emotional recess which can then be used to build the tension further and better for the subsequent grisly wood chipper scene.

The script does not contain her murder—only the aftermath, though I don't know if that's because the posted script was retroactively matched to the print or if it was shot to match this script.  Search for "Jean sits" in [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Fargo.html) to see for yourself.